# Dynamically created anchor doesn't work after setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, timer, tags, click

Hi I make a Timer with Javascript, it works fine. And when it finish the 5 seconds count the code enable a target for open a web, but when I click its dont working. I try this code outside the timer and its works perfectly. What is the error?

```
<?php
$windowsOpen .= "window.open('$value', '_blank');";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function countDown(secs,elem){
var element = document.getElementById(elem);
element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+secs+" seconds";
if(secs < 1){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    element.innerHTML='<p><a href="#" onclick="<?= $windowsOpen; ?>">Click to open webs</a></p>';
}
secs--;
var timer = setTimeout('countDown('+secs+',"'+elem+'")',1000);
}
</script>
<div id="status"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">countDown(5,"status");</script>
```

Comment: What are you expecting your `onclick="<?= $windowsOpen; ?>"` to do?

Comment: Sorry, I forget add php code. Now the code its complete

Comment: <p><a href="#" onclick="<?= $windowsOpen; ?>">Click to open webs</a></p>  With that html line I can make a target for open a web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline event handlers are essentially eval inside HTML markup - they're bad practice and result in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead: developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

If you *absolutely need* the window opener to be handled with Javascript instead of the browser's nice native behavior, then define the URL you want people to navigate to upfront, and then attach a listener to the element when it's created:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.google.com';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var url = '<?=$url;?>';
var timer;
function countDown(secs,elem){
  var element = document.getElementById(elem);
  element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+secs+" seconds";
  if(secs < 1){
    element.innerHTML='<p><a href="#">Click to open link</a></p>';
    element.querySelector('a')
      .addEventListener('click', () => {
        window.open(url);
      });
  } else {
    secs--;
    setTimeout(countDown, 1000, secs, elem);
  }
}
</script>
<div id="status"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">countDown(5,"status");</script>
```

You should also avoid using `eval` in your `setTimeout` - always write out functions in normal JS, rather than as strings to be parsed into functions.

But it would be much less user-unfriendly if you would let them click the link themselves, using the browser's normal behavior:

```
element.innerHTML='<p><a href="#">Click to open link</a></p>';
element.querySelector('a')
  .href = url;
```